# Generic "multi-contains" for maps

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I frequently encounter the usecase where I have to check whether a set of keys is contained in a set of nested maps. I currently have an implementation for a number of practical nesting depths that look something like this:

```
  template< typename Key1T, typename Key2T, typename ValueT >
  bool contains
    ( std::map< Key1T, std::map< Key2T, ValueT > > const & m
    , Key1T                                        const & k1
    , Key2T                                        const & k2
    )
  {
    return m.contains( k1 ) && m.at( k1 ).contains( k2 );
  }
```

I was wondering if there was a way to implement this as a single function for all possible nesting depths, maybe facilitating variadic templates?

Comment: Side note: Your current implementation looks up `k1` twice if it's found which isn't optimal. You should look it up via `find`, and use the result of that `find` to both work out whether it exists and to then to use the result of that `find` _again_ to look into the next level,.

Comment: I am kind of curiuous what your are trying to model... but I have the feeling you lack some abstractions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I question the motives behind doing something like this, but here you go:

```cpp
template<typename FirstKey, typename InnerMap, typename... RemainingKeys>
bool contains(std::map<FirstKey, InnerMap> const& m,
              FirstKey const& firstKey,
              RemainingKeys const&... remainingKeys)
{
    auto it = m.find(firstKey);
    if constexpr (sizeof...(remainingKeys) == 0) {
        return it != m.end();
    } else {
        return it != m.end() && contains(it->second, remainingKeys...);
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Y9E5shdvM)

Comment: Instead of repeating yourself with `it != m.end()`, you could also write `bool result = m.find(firstKey) != m.end();` and use this `result` in both branches.

Comment: @JanSchultke You still need `it` in the recursive `contains` call. Sure you could do `bool result = it != m.end()` but I don't see the point. It's not like I'm repeating a long piece of code many times.

Comment: You're right. It's a trade-off between having `it != m.end()` appear twice and adding an extra `bool result = it != m.end();` line then.